# Dummit Foote 10.5.1(d) commutative diagram of exact sequences.

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

I solved other problems, except (d): if $\beta$ is injective, $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ are surjective, then $\gamma$ is injective.

Unlike others, I don't know where to start.

Comment: This is a typo in the book: the first $\gamma$ should be a $\varphi$. See [the errata](http://www.cems.uvm.edu/~foote/errata_3rd_edition.pdf) on Foote's webpage.

Comment: Yep, a typo, you can easily find a counterexample to the statement as it is written.

Comment: Thanks, guys! I lost a few hours thinking over this.

Comment: @Dylan Making your comment an answer, perhaps with a counter example, will resolve this question. Please consider this. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

As the comments mention, this exercise is false as stated.  Here's a counterexample: let $A$ and $B$ be groups, with usual inclusion and projection homomorphisms $$\iota_A(a) = (a,1),$$ $$\iota_B(b) = (1,b)$$ and $$\pi_B(a,b) = b.$$

Then the following diagram meets the stated requirements, except $\pi_B$ is not injective.

$$\require{AMScd} 
\begin{CD}
A @>{\iota_A}>> A\times B @>{\iota_B \circ \pi_B}>>   A\times B\\
@V{\operatorname{Id}}VV @V{\operatorname{Id}}VV  @V{\pi_B}VV\\
A @>{\iota_A}>> A \times B @>{\pi_B}>> B
\end{CD}$$

This indeed exploits the fact that $\varphi$ is not required to be surjective.